# OpenAL - Play Hosted .wav on server

Tags: c++, openal

Is it possible to play a .wav hosted on a fileserver http://example.com/mysound.wav

Or mp3/ogg

Answer (score 0):

Use libcurl to get your file in your scene loading. With buffer in memory, you can use method "alutLoadWAVMemory" from ALUT. FreeALUT is a good and updated library. https://github.com/vancegroup/freealut